# Fill Google Form from Other Google Form Responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form that users initially submit, say 3 weeks before an event occurs.

When the event gets closer they need to provide a final update. I would like for them to be able to select the event, probably based on the event name, and then have the form prefill in the information it already has on file (initial responses) for that event. Then the user can go in there and tweak the information and provide final details, without having to reinput all of the information all over again.

How do I do this? :-\ Thanks!

hunna03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Google Apps Script.

So for instance, the result of the original Google Form can be stored in a Google Sheet, whose fields can be used to generate the new form.

The related documentation on creating the Google Form can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/